# How to count comma seperated repeated values in a pandas column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe column like this:

```
1    Applied Learning, Literacy & Language
2             Literacy & Language, Special Needs
3            Math & Science, Literacy & Language
4            Literacy & Language, Math & Science
6               Math & Science, Applied Learning
7                               Applied Learning
8                            Literacy & Language
10                                Math & Science...
```

There are comma seperated values in each row. What I want is to count the occurance of all the unique values. For eg: Math & Science appears 4 times. So the count for Math & Science should be 4. I tried the following code:

```
cato=response['Category'].str.split(',')
cat_set=[]
for i in cato.dropna():
    cat_set.extend(i)
plt1=pd.Series(cat_set).value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).to_frame()
```

But the problem is, this code works for small datasets, but it takes a lot of time for a large dataset. Any solutions for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is built specifically for high performance of tasks like this one.

Say you start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['Applied Learning, Literacy & Language', 'Literacy & Language, Special Needs']})
```

then do

```
import collections
import itertools
>>> collections.Counter(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v.split(',') for v in df.Category))

Counter({' Literacy & Language': 1,
         ' Special Needs': 1,
         'Applied Learning': 1,
         'Literacy & Language': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using `collections.Counter` and `itertools.chain`. Particular care needs to be taken to strip whitespace.

For performance, you should test and benchmark with your data.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

s = pd.Series(['Applied Learning, Literacy & Language', 'Literacy & Language, Special Needs',
               'Math & Science, Literacy & Language', 'Literacy & Language, Math & Science',
               'Math & Science, Applied Learning', 'Applied Learning', 'Literacy & Language',
               'Math & Science'])

res = Counter(map(str.strip, chain.from_iterable(s.str.split(','))))

Counter({'Applied Learning': 3,
         'Literacy & Language': 5,
         'Math & Science': 4,
         'Special Needs': 1})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `scikit-learn` -

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vec = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x.split(',')], lowercase=False)
counts = vec.fit_transform(df['text']) # actual count, output will be a sparse matrix
dict(zip(vec.get_feature_names(), counts.sum(axis=0).tolist()[0]))
```

Here the `CountVectorizer` module is a `scikit-learn` implementation for any bag of words modelling in Natural Language Processing.

You can use the `counts` object directly as a sparse matrix, efficient for storing and computation, you can also perform operations like `.sum(axis=0)` which sums by column. Once done, just merge it with the `vocabulary` to get what you want

**Output**

```
{'Applied Learning': 3, 'Literacy & Language': 5, 'Math & Science': 4, 'Special
Needs': 1}
```

This applies to all the words across that column

Comment: The use of `CountVectorizer` is very cool, but I think it's an overkill here, as the distribution among instances is unneeded. Nevertheless, nice.

Comment: @AmiTavory totally agree - My first goto no doubt would have been `collections.Counter`, but since it was *taken*, couldn't resist putting this in :-P

Answer (score 1):

```
split = response['Category'].str.split(', ')

s = set()
for row in split:
    [s.add(el) for el in row]

for topic in s:    
    df[topic] = a.map(lambda x: topic in x)
```

This leads to a df with

```
                                       0  Literacy & Language  Math & Science  \
0  Applied Learning, Literacy & Language                 True           False   
1     Literacy & Language, Special Needs                 True           False   
2    Math & Science, Literacy & Language                 True            True   
3    Literacy & Language, Math & Science                 True            True   
4       Math & Science, Applied Learning                False            True   
5                       Applied Learning                False           False   
6                    Literacy & Language                 True           False   
7                         Math & Science                False            True   

   Applied Learning  Special Needs  
0              True          False  
1             False           True  
2             False          False  
3             False          False  
4              True          False  
5              True          False  
6             False          False  
7             False          False
```

So that you can calculate the sum of True-values:

```
for topic in s:
    print(topic, df[topic].sum())

Literacy & Language 5
Math & Science 4
Applied Learning 3
Special Needs 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add another possible solution. I was also trying to solve that problem and got something like this by using nested comprehensions:

```
example = pd.Series(['a', 'b, c', 'a, b', 'b', 'd', 'c'])

values = []

[[values.append(key) for key in record.split(', ')] for record in example.values.tolist()]

series = pd.Series(values)
series.value_counts().sort_index()
```